# du command on CentOS / RHEL 7 excludes directories block size

Tags: centos, filesystems, rhel, disk-usage

Say you have a directory named /tmp/xyz and you create 2 empty sub-directories named a & b.
Now, if you run

```
du -sh /tmp/xyz
```

on a Debian / Ubuntu distros and on CentOS 6, you'll get 12K (3 per each dir * block size=4KB).

On CentOS / RHEL 7 (as opposed to CentOS 6) you would get on the other hand 0, which I find surprising.
Is the disk space not reserved somehow on CentOS/RHEL ? I could not find any hidden switch that might have been executed on one distro and isn't executed on the other.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is due to the filesystem, not to the `du` command.

The size of a (small) directory is 0 on CentOS/RHEL7 because it's using XFS, rather than the ext4 filesystem on CentOS/RHEL6.

> Most symbolic links and directory files are small files. XFS allows these files to be stored in inodes for increased performance

Comment: Thanks about the XFS explanation, now it makes perfect sense